# Такое вообще возможно, что приложение имеет ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE, а WebView в нем - ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT?

Tags: android, android-webview

Хочу сделать так, чтобы все приложение имело только **ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE** и изменять ориентацию нельзя было (это сделано). Но в этом приложении есть  **WebView**, в нем нужна **ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT** или чтобы ориентация менялась взависимости от поворота экрана, но только в **WebView** (т.е. какбы внутри самого **WebView** поворот на 90 градусов), а не самого приложения. 
Устанавливал для **WebView Rotation = 90**, но результат не тот (поворачивает сам **WebView**, а не его содержимое).

Это вообще возможно сделать? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы моете попробовать унаследовать свой собственный класс от WebView:

```
public class VerticalWebView extends WebView {
    final boolean topDown = true;

    public VerticalWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (topDown) {
            canvas.translate(getHeight(), 0);
            canvas.rotate(90);
        } else {
            canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
            canvas.rotate(-90);
        }
        canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло :)